# Efficient way to store historical (shadow) tables in MySQL (or another SQL engine)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

When developing my own system with API, I store my resources in a database.
The structure of one table (`products`) is like this:

| id | name | description | image_id | updated_at | updated_by | updated_with | is_deleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | attribute | attribute | relation | timestamp op update | user id of update | client id of update | boolean |

Because I want to have track on all changes of this table, I also made a shadow table (`products_HISTORY`) with one extra column at the beginning (`_hid` for History ID) to keep track on the history records. I also made a trigger in MySQL that creates a new row in this shadow table on every creation or update (not on deletion, because I do soft-deletion). To get the value of `created_at`, I request the earliest row of the resource from the shadow table. The same for `deleted_at`, but only if `is_deleted` is true.

All works very well, but in the near future I want to implement a mail service where the mail is saved in the MySQL database. Because e-mails can be easily 25 MB, and there is a record added with a fully copy on every change, my database will be 1GB large after 40 changes of a 25 MB fail. That is not very efficient.

My question: Is there a more efficient way to save the shadow table? Is there special software for this or is this supported by MySQL (or another MySQL like engine)? I was thinking about some Git-like solution, where only the actual changes are saved + a full content of the last version (your current checkout code). Is there already something like this?

Thanks in advance

Ben

PS: At the moment I use Laravel and Laravel works very well with MySQL. If there is some solution that works fine with laravel, that would be nice, but if not, your answer is also welcome.

Comment: See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/system-versioned-tables/

Comment: @Akina Does that also support use of an extra column like my `_hid`?

Comment: I don't understand your question... anycase you may test (for example, on some online fiddle).

Comment: @Akina My question was if it was possible to have my normal table, but that the historical rows all have a _hid column when using system_versioning.

Comment: I looked to this solution and it is very nice, but the problem is that it seems that there isn't any storage saving advantage. If I have a record of 1GB and I change one char, my table will become 2GB. If I change it again, it will become 3GB. However, in a system that is like Git, it will only save the changes. My table isn't 3GB then, but 1.01GB or something.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have track on all changes of that table, you can use a laravel package that called [activitylog](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-activitylog). Using that package you can track all activity on a model. just put `use LogsActivity;` on your model like example;

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Spatie\Activitylog\Traits\LogsActivity;

class Product extends Model
{
    use LogsActivity;
        
    protected static $logAttributes = ['name', 'text'];
}
```

Comment: But I want to save the information in my database.

Comment: what information? it can log/save all information of the table that logged

Comment: All changes that are made to the table should be saved in the same database.

Comment: so what? It will save on the same database too

Comment: But I prefer a solution by the database itself.

Comment: `If there is some solution that works fine with laravel` you ask solution for laravel, so I provide it. and as far as I know there is no built-in function/feature of the database for your need.

Comment: I meant a database software solution. For example, MySQL is supported by Laravel and Node4J isn't supported by Laravel, but if there is a versioning solution for it, I accept both. I don't want my solution working on Laravel, but with Laravel.

Comment: so what do you mean `solution by the database itself` ? you need database recommendation that support that?

Comment: Database software that keeps versioning of all rows in a table and saves this history very storage efficient (maybe like Git saves projects). If Laravel directly work with this database solution, that would be nice, otherwise I will find or make a package for it.

Comment: so your question is offtopic here. I already suggested you the package for it but you ignore it.

Comment: No, it is not offtopic. The solution MUST be a database software one. However, it is possible that that software isn't supported by Laravel.